# Replying to an email from a domain email alias

Tags: configuration, email-server, windows-server-2012-r2, alias, email

We have a multi-store set up in nopCommerce 3.20 with SSL enabled.

Our environment info as follows,

- Windows 2012 R2 VPS Server.
- .Net 4.5, SQL Server 2012 Express
- Multi    SSL in Same IP using SNI.
- Win Pleask version 12.0.18.
- Email Server - MailEnable Standard Edition 7.53

### Scenario

A domain (say domainalias.com. As standard nop setup) set up as a domain alias of maindomain.com in our VPS. Nop Commerce website is working fine with SSL for multi-store. Right now emails of domainalias.com works fine as email alias for maindomain.com. But problem comes when you try to reply for an email of domainalias.com. Right now replies only can be sent via maindomain.com not as from domain1.com

We are in a situation, where website should work as a part of alias as per nop multi-store design. But email should work as separate email server. That means, when a email from domainalias.com is replied, email should be sent as email@domainalias.com instead of email@maindomain.com

I am aware of one solution. It’s to buy a email server from service provider such as Google and update MX record in the vps for domainalias.com. But my company wouldn't not prefer this as costly.

### Question 1

Is there any elegant solution you guys ever come across for this type email server configuration with multi-store environments? Any settings/config on Mail Enable can do the trick?

### Question 2

Another suggestion which I came across is "Forwarding". Set up a 2 website hosting accounts in pleask for maindomain.com and domainalias.com and then and set the Forwarding type as "Frame forwarding" so that the destination address will not change in the address bar. This will solve email issue but I am not sure if SSL for website will work or not. Any idea on this weather if SSL will work or not?

### Update

I think question was misunderstood. There is no issues on nop commerce sending order emails with corresponding domian or domainalias. I mentioned nop commerce only to get the full picture of our VPS infrastructure and the reason behind why its configured like that.

My issue is using mail server for normal email communication. Its nothing to do with nop commerce. Say, you are sending an email to sales@domainalias.com asking if a certain product is in stock, but when store owner clicks reply, by default "from" email for that reply turns to sales@domain.com instead of sales@domainalias.com. We wanted to have each domain to be shown as not related to each other for customers. Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't mean to sound snippy and delete this if it is offensive; but depending on your level of need I can tell you how to do it in `postfix` on a 'nix-like system. But with Windows I think you are stuck.

Comment: Did you use mailenable webmail to send/read email? Or mail client like Outlook/Thunderbird?

Comment: Hi Masegaloeh, Thanks for your reply. We are using outlook as our email client. We did try creating 2 profiles on outlook. one for domain and other for domain alias. then we ran into problem of duplicate emails. same email was downloaded twice.

Comment: Thanks for down-voting guys, which mean's my question is not clear? I did about few weeks of research and long discussion with our service provider. Still couldn't get a work around. so posted here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're OK with a solution that involves a configuration change in Outlook, you can add an additional e-mail account within your existing Outlook profile (don't add another profile).  If your mail server preserves the fact messages were addressed to your alias address, Outlook will recognize this and automatically use this second account when you compose replies to those e-mails.

Configure the additional e-mail account as follows:

1. Create the account as a POP3 account
2. Specify the alias e-mail address
3. Use **127.0.0.1** for the Incoming/POP3 Server (you don't really want this account to be used to download mail...as you've noted, doing so results in duplicate e-mails)
4. Provide the correct Outbound/SMTP server details
5. After adding this additional account, you may wish to edit Outlook's Send & Receive settings to prevent it from attempting to check for new messages from this alias account to prevent unwanted error messages.

Because you provided correct values for the Outbound/SMTP server for this account, your replies will be sent successfully, but because you provided a bogus value for the Incoming/POP3 server you won't end up downloading duplicate messages.

Comment: Hi Twisty, thanks for the reply. I did try similar case as you explained. Its at https://axicoms.zendesk.com/entries/63490-How-to-send-from-an-email-alias-in-Outlook-2007 But using this, when every time i try reply for an alias email, "From" field defaults to default email account, which is main domain. Is there any workaround to ensure, when you click reply to an alias email, automatically pick that alias email as from address rather than i manually select from account button in outlook?

Comment: This is answer gives more relevant information. So awarded bounty.

Comment: Jeyara, in your environment if this solution isn't causing Outlook to automatically default to the correct From address when replying to messages, my research indicates there is no built-in way to convince Outlook to do so.  You may wish to investigate the option of adding a custom button to Outlook's toolbar that replies to the current e-mail using the alias' account.  This link isn't _exactly_ what you're looking for, but might be a starting point: http://www.slipstick.com/developer/send-using-default-or-specific-account/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any kind of solutions that involves touching the SMTP server is going to work.

The information you want to work with ("which domain is being used") is known to nopCommerce and whatever web server you're using. However, nopCommerce is the "agent" acting on it and sending email. It should be the one carrying the logic to decide which email address to use in the "From" field of the replies.

I see a few options:

- Patch nopCommerce to understand the domain in use and change the "From" field accordingly
- Configure an independent nopCommerce installation for the alias domain (added maintenance)
- Why is it important what the reply comes from? Choose a new/neutral domain that can be used by nopCommerce in both domains and don't worry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I guess you misunderstood the question. Its not about how nop commerce sends email. It is working without any issue. Our only issue is if a customer sends email to domainalias.com, then we are forced to reply from domain.com . not from alias. That's my question on how to fix this. Choosing a common domain won't present 2 stores as separate entities for customer s.

Comment: I understood it but the problem is that nopCommerce is not being smart enough to understand that and change the FROM field accordingly. Unfortunately, support for nopCommerce is beyond the scope of ServerFault. What you need is to modify the message in transit based on the contents of the message body/headers so the FROM address is adjusted correctly (i.e. you let noCommerce send it using the wrong domain and later fix it). This is called Transport Rules in Exchange but I don't know if MailEnable supports it http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124703(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: gtirloni, still you have mis-understood the question. See my "Update" section in the question. thanks.